# node.js - Call javascript variable from within mysql query

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am trying to call javascript variables from within the mySQL query.
The lines are executed with node.js environment, using syntax [node (filename)]. I understand that I could potentially do this query in 2 steps, by first query the value of min_value, and then query the max_value.

**Can the request be executed in one mySQL query?**

Preferably I would like to keep the code structure with vanilla js and mySQL, without adding node.js-specific commands, nor needing to load extra packages.

Javascript variables:

```
let min_value = 100;
let max_value = 300;
```

This works:

```
sql = `
 SELECT
   acronym,
   salaries
 FROM 
   employees
 WHERE
   salaries BETWEEN 100 and 300
ORDER BY acronym;
`;
```

This does not works:

```
sql = `
 SELECT
   acronym,
   salaries
 FROM 
   employees
 WHERE
   salaries BETWEEN ($min_value) and ($max_value)
ORDER BY acronym;
`;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), with the `${variable}` placeholder syntax:

```js
let min_value = 100;
let max_value = 300;
let sql1 = `
 SELECT
   acronym,
   salaries
 FROM 
   employees
 WHERE
   salaries BETWEEN (${min_value}) and (${max_value})
ORDER BY acronym;
`;

let sql2 = `
 SELECT
   acronym,
   salaries
 FROM 
   employees
 WHERE
   salaries BETWEEN ${min_value} and ${max_value}
ORDER BY acronym;
`;

console.log(sql1);
console.log(sql2);
```

Comment: @henetik: Your answer works with both (${min_value}) and ${min_value}. I assume if one would want to follow exact syntax in scenario of having value instead of variables, I would go without the parenthesis. If you could please update the answer with both variation (without and with parenthesis), I'll go ahead and accept the answer.